# In Xcode, any hot key for filter box in Project navigator?

Tags: xcode, macos

Is there any hot key in Xcode that can go to filter box in Project navigator DIRECTLY?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

If you want to filter right hand side when looking for components use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (small caps L).